# Merging data sets with unequal observations

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

I have two data sets, one is the subset of another but the subset has additional column, with lesser observations.

Basically, I have a unique ID assigned to each participants, and then a HHID, the house id from which they were recruited (eg 15 participants recruited from 11 houses).

```
> Healthdata <- data.frame(ID = gl(15, 1), HHID = c(1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,6,7,8,9,10,11))
> Healthdata
```

Now, I have a subset of data with only one participant per household, chosen who spent longer hours watching television. In this subset data, I have computed socioeconomic score (SSE) for each house.

```
> set.seed(1)
> Healthdata.1<- data.frame(ID=sample(1:15,11, replace=F), HHID=gl(11,1), SSE = sample(-6.5:3.5, 11, replace=TRUE))
> Healthdata.1
```

Now, I want to assign the SSE from the subset (Healthdata.1) to unique participants of bigger data (Healthdata) such that, participants from the same house gets the same score.

I can't merge this simply, because the data sets have different number of observations, 15 in the bigger one but only 11 in the subset.

Is there any way to do this in R? I am very new to it and I am stuck with this.

I want the required output as something like below, ie ID (participants) from same HHID (house) should have same SSE score. The following output is just meant for an example of what I need, the above seed will not give the same output.

```
 ID HHID SSE
 1    1  -6.5
 2    2  -5.5
 3    2  -5.5
 4    3   3.3
 5    4   3.0
 6    5   2.58
 7    5   2.58
 8    5   2.58
 9    6  -3.05
10    6  -3.05
11    7  -1.2
12    8   2.5
13    9   1.89
14   10   1.88
15   11  -3.02
```

Thanks.

Comment: can you show the required output - as i can see different answers below

Comment: they aren't actuallt different. This: ```merge(Healthdata,Healthdata.1,all.x=TRUE,by='ID')``` is equivalent to ```join(Healthdata, Healthdata.1, type = "left", by = "ID")``` I just find more intuitive plyr than merge.

Comment: @MartínBel, I tried this. But, it works partially. It only merges one of the participants and gives NA to the value of SSE to other one. I want each participant coming from same house be assigned same SSE, and not SSEscore for one and NA for the other one, when two or more participants have the same HHID

Comment: @PrasannaNanda, Thanks, please see the updated question, with the required output.

Comment: where does 6.5 comes form your output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to merge by `HHID`, not `ID`.  Note this is somewhat confusing because the ids from the supergroup are from a different set than from the subgroup.  I.e. ID.x == 4 != ID.y == 4 (in fact, in this case they are in different households).  Because of that I left both ID columns here to avoid ambiguity, but you can easily subset the result to show only the ID.x one,

```
> merge(Healthdata, Healthdata.1, by='HHID')
   HHID ID.x ID.y  SSE
1     1    1    4 -5.5
2     2    2    6  0.5
3     2    3    6  0.5
4     3    4    8 -2.5
5     4    5   11  1.5
6     5    6    3 -1.5
7     5    7    3 -1.5
8     5    8    3 -1.5
9     6    9    9  0.5
10    6   10    9  0.5
11    7   11   10  3.5
12    8   12   14 -2.5
13    9   13    5  1.5
14   10   14    1  3.5
15   11   15    2 -4.5
```

Comment: Thanks. A little thing makes a huge difference. It worked. Thank you very much. To get rid of all those .x, I used join(Healthdata, Healthdata.1, type = "left", by = "HHID")

Answer (score 2):

You can use `merge` , By default it will merge by columns intersections.

```
merge(Healthdata,Healthdata.1,all.x=TRUE)
   ID HHID SSE
1   1    1  NA
2   2    2  NA
3   3    2  NA
4   4    3  NA
5   5    4  NA
6   6    5  NA
7   7    5  NA
8   8    5  NA
9   9    6 0.7
10 10    6  NA
11 11    7  NA
12 12    8  NA
13 13    9  NA
14 14   10  NA
15 15   11  NA
```

Or you can choose by which column you merge :

```
merge(Healthdata,Healthdata.1,all.x=TRUE,by='ID')
```

Comment: Tried this as well. It only merges one of the participants and gives NA to the value of SSE to other one. I want each participant coming from same house be assigned same SSE, and not SSEscore for one and NA for the other one, when two or more participants have the same HHID. I have updated the question with required output.

Comment: I don't know where 6.5 comes form your output ? Are you using another seed to generate the data? did you try to merhe by HHID? `merge(Healthdata,Healthdata.1,all.x=TRUE,by='HHID')`?

Comment: sorry the required output was just meant to show how I want the output to look like after merging.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(plyr)
join(Healthdata, Healthdata.1)

# Inner Join
join(Healthdata, Healthdata.1, type = "inner", by = "ID")

# Left Join
# I believe this is what you are after
join(Healthdata, Healthdata.1, type = "left", by = "ID")
```

Comment: I tried this. But, it works partially. It only merges one of the participants and gives NA to the value of SSE to other one. I want each participant coming from same house be assigned same SSE, and not SSEscore for one and NA for the other one, when two or more participants have the same HHID. I have updated the question with required output.

Comment: use join(Healthdata, Healthdata.1, type = "left", by = "HHID")